# Run a function on frame load Actionscript 3.0

Tags: flash, actionscript, air

I am creating a mobile app using actionscript and flash (I know its outdated).
I was wondering if there is a way I can execute a function when I load onto a new frame.
for example:
when entering frame 10 I would like to call a function to retrieve some information from a database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add frame listener.

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onFrameEnter);
```